# Where can i find a CMS UML example?

Tags: content-management-system, uml

There are plenty of people saying that is it useless to develop your own CMS. I deduce that 'computer science' has enough experience in developing CMS. But I can not find an example of the UML of a CMS. An open source CMS or whatever, I need 'inspiration'.

If you have a link, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the best you'll find is the database schema for existing CMSs like wordpress or drupal. You could see this schema as a UML class diagram (some CMSs don't use foreign keys, in those cases, you'll need to complement the schema info to deduce the associations between classes).

You could also try a reverse engineering tool and apply it to the CMS you want to get some diagrams out of it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me a little more please ? I am confused with the UML schema, the database schema and the fact that I am using a NO_SQL database (GAE). I do not know if the UML schema and the database schema have a lot of difference (and which is the most important of them). And I do not know if doing these schema will be usefull for me because I understood that NO_SQL have no relation. Any advice is greatly welcome. Thank you.

Comment: UML class diagrams can be easily used to represent database schemas (of course, they can represent more things than that). Database schemas are usually modeled using ER (which is just another modeling language that for your purpose can be considered as almost equal to UML class diagrams). Regarding NO_SQL I guess you could use separate classes to define the structures you may use in your NO_SQL (like json schemas if it's the case).

Comment: Tks, I have searched all day long. And I read that Drupal was not done using Object so it is difficult to have an UML....

Comment: that's why I said the best you would get is the database schema. Trying to reverse engineer the php code of Drupal (or Wordpres,...) is very challenging.